# JAVA ; expected not a statement else without if

Tags: java, if-statement

Hi I was wondering what's wrong with my code I get the errors stated in the title. What is wrong with this? Thanks in advance. Why do I need so many details, I feel like I've described it well enough.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CombinationLock
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter three uppercase letters.");
        System.out.println("Hit enter after each letter.");
        String str1 = in.nextLine();
        String str2 = in.nextLine();
        String str3 = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Would you like to open the lock?");
        if(Yes)
            Scanner lol = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter the combination for this lock.");
            System.out.println("Hit enter after each letter");
            String str4 = lol.nextLine();
            String str5 = lol.nextLine();
            String str6 = lol.nextLine();
            if(str4.equals(str1))
                if (str5.equals(str2))
                    if(str6.equals(str3))
                        System.out.println("Congratulations you have unlocked the lock :)");
                    else
                        System.out.println("Sorry the combination you have input is not correct :/");
                else
                    System.out.println("Sorry the combination you have input is not correct :/");
            else
                System.out.println("Sorry the combination you have input is not correct :/");
        else
            System.out.println("This lock has been locked enter code here with the letters that you have just input.");
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you haven't described it well enough. What is the full error message? Which line does it point to?

Comment: If you are going to post a question about an error/exception you recieve, PLEASE post a stack trace, and point us to the line the error happens on. Sure in most cases, most of us could find the error, but a little bit of work from you saves us a bunch of time.

Comment: When a compiler see `if-else` without `{}`…it cries.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ That's not necessarily true. (As a programmer though, maybe)

Comment: @Cruncher There is no stack trace because it won't compile .. but same idea holds ;-)

Comment: @user2864740 Fair enough. I used the term "stack trace" more generally than I should have :)

Comment: @user2864740 I suspect something like this probably came from the programmer having previous experience in VB or Python as the indentation is all correct.

Comment: That is what you are seeing here.its always better and good practise to use {} .otherwise its hard to find where the block is ending . If its a simple if else that is ok.if you have nested ,then everyone ends up with opening their eyes bigger to trace the mistake.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ While on the topic of nesting here, "deep nesting" is generally considered bad practice. If you can write the same code "shallower" is usually preferred.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `{}`!

There :

```
    if(Yes)
        Scanner lol = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the combination for this lock.");
```

This if-statement is only for this line `Scanner lol = new Scanner(System.in);`

So the last else-statement is not connected to any if-statement.

This is how you should use `{}` for getting the right output and to be clear what is for what :

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter three uppercase letters.");
    System.out.println("Hit enter after each letter.");
    String str1 = in.nextLine();
    String str2 = in.nextLine();
    String str3 = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Would you like to open the lock?");
    if (Yes) {
        Scanner lol = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the combination for this lock.");
        System.out.println("Hit enter after each letter");
        String str4 = lol.nextLine();
        String str5 = lol.nextLine();
        String str6 = lol.nextLine();
        if (str4.equals(str1)) {
            if (str5.equals(str2)) {
                if (str6.equals(str3)) {
                    System.out.println("Congratulations you have unlocked the lock :)");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Sorry the combination you have input is not correct :/");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry the combination you have input is not correct :/");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry the combination you have input is not correct :/");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("This lock has been locked enter code here with the letters that you have just input.");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a curly braces `{` after the first `if (Yes)`

```
    if(Yes) {
        Scanner lol = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the combination for this lock.");
        System.out.println("Hit enter after each letter");
        String str4 = lol.nextLine();
        String str5 = lol.nextLine();
        String str6 = lol.nextLine();
        if(str4.equals(str1))
            if (str5.equals(str2))
                if(str6.equals(str3))
                    System.out.println("Congratulations you have unlocked the lock :)");
                else
                    System.out.println("Sorry the combination you have input is not correct :/");
            else
                System.out.println("Sorry the combination you have input is not correct :/");
        else
            System.out.println("Sorry the combination you have input is not correct :/");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("This lock has been locked enter code here with the letters that you have just input.");
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, here is my take (extracted from a previous comment of mine):

> I use braces for *every* if statement (except for quick pre/post-condition single-line if (..) throw .. statements). I consider myself an seasoned developer, and I also recommend that beginners use braces for *every* if statement ..

Following such advice would have prevented the syntax error to begin with ;-)

Anyway, that was followed up with Cruncher saying:

> .."deep nesting" is generally considered bad practice. If you can write the same code "shallower" is usually preferred.

So, I'd like to address the end cascade of if-else statements. As really, adding braces to them really doesn't make the code any easier to read. However, what *does* make the code easier to adjusting the approach such that it becomes "shallower". (And it also removes some redundant lines.)

```
// ..
if(Yes) {
    // ..
    if(str4.equals(str1)
       && str5.equals(str2)
       && str6.equals(str3)) {
         System.out.println("Congratulations you have unlocked the lock :)");
    } else {
         System.out.println("Sorry the combination you have input is not correct :/");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("This lock has been locked enter code here with the letters..");
}
```

Comment: +1, I didn't even notice that the same print statement was being used in multiple places.

Answer (score 2):

Every if block, if said block contains more than a single statement, should be surrounded by curly braces.  If it is a single statement, it's still recommended.  (Note: a nested if can count as a single statement! Which is why you should generally always use curly braces whether they're technically needed or not) You can nest additional if blocks inside each if condition.

```
if(someCondition)
{
    //do some stuff
    if(someOtherCondition)
    {
        //do some additional stuff
    }
}
else
{
    //do some other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically you are missing curly brace after if. But even if you fix it there is no variable called `Yes`. If you want to run it always, use `true`

```
if(true) {
```